# Concatenate multiple columns based on conditions on datetimes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a data frame like this

```
ID <- c("1D01","1D02","1D03","1D04","1D05","1D06","1D07","1D08","1D09")
A <- c("2020-05-29 00:00:13","2020-06-09 00:00:13","2020-06-06 00:00:13",
       "2020-06-03 00:00:13","2020-06-03 00:00:13","2020-06-03 00:00:13",
       "2020-06-03 00:00:13","2020-06-03 00:00:13",NA)
B <- c("2020-06-01 00:00:13","2020-06-08 00:00:13","2020-06-19 00:00:13",
       "2020-06-21 00:00:13","2020-06-03 00:00:13","2020-06-03 00:00:13",
       "2020-06-07 00:00:13","2020-06-07 00:00:13",NA)
C <- c("2020-06-03 00:00:13","2020-06-07 00:00:13","2020-06-01 00:00:13",
       "2020-06-11 00:00:13","2020-06-03 00:00:13","2020-06-03 00:00:13",
       "2020-06-03 00:00:13",NA,"2020-06-07 00:00:13")
D <- c("2020-06-04 00:00:13","2020-06-05 00:00:13","2020-06-08 00:00:13",
       "2020-06-01 00:00:13","2020-06-04 00:00:13","2020-06-03 00:00:13",
       "2020-06-01 00:00:13",NA,"2020-06-03 00:00:13")

df <- data.frame(ID,A,B,C,D)
df$A <- as.POSIXct(df$A) 
df$B <- as.POSIXct(df$B) 
df$C <- as.POSIXct(df$C) 
df$D <- as.POSIXct(df$D)
```

I am creating a column called `path` based on the following conditions of other column dates and based on ascending order of dates

1. Look at the order of datetimes across the 4 columns (A,B,C,D), concatenate the columns based on ascending order of datetimes. For ex: **A_B_C_D** if A has the smallest datetime and D has the longest datetime.
2. If 2 or more columns have the same datetime, concatenate without the underscore. For ex: **A_BC_D** if B and C have same datetimes
3. If a column has NA, exclude that column when concatenating. For ex: **A_B_D** if C has NA

My desired output is

```
    ID                   A                   B                   C                   D    path
1 1D01 2020-05-29 00:00:13 2020-06-01 00:00:13 2020-06-03 00:00:13 2020-06-04 00:00:13 A_B_C_D
2 1D02 2020-06-09 00:00:13 2020-06-08 00:00:13 2020-06-07 00:00:13 2020-06-05 00:00:13 D_C_B_A
3 1D03 2020-06-06 00:00:13 2020-06-19 00:00:13 2020-06-01 00:00:13 2020-06-08 00:00:13 C_A_D_B
4 1D04 2020-06-03 00:00:13 2020-06-21 00:00:13 2020-06-11 00:00:13 2020-06-01 00:00:13 D_A_C_B
5 1D05 2020-06-03 00:00:13 2020-06-03 00:00:13 2020-06-03 00:00:13 2020-06-04 00:00:13   ABC_D
6 1D06 2020-06-03 00:00:13 2020-06-03 00:00:13 2020-06-03 00:00:13 2020-06-03 00:00:13    ABCD
7 1D07 2020-06-03 00:00:13 2020-06-07 00:00:13 2020-06-03 00:00:13 2020-06-01 00:00:13  D_AC_B
8 1D08 2020-06-03 00:00:13 2020-06-07 00:00:13                <NA>                <NA>     A_B
9 1D09                <NA>                <NA> 2020-06-07 00:00:13 2020-06-03 00:00:13     D_C
```

I am trying to do it this way but clearly not working

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(path = case_when(
    A >= B >= C >= D  ~ "(A_B_C_D)",
    TRUE           ~ "(ABD_C)"))
```

How do I get my desired output? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this achieve what you are looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)

df_out <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  arrange(ID, value) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(name2 = if_else(value == lead(value), name, paste0(name, "_")),
         name2 = if_else(is.na(name2), name, name2),
         path = paste(name2, collapse = ""),
         name2 = NULL) %>%
  pivot_wider()
```

Comment: This works like charm and is also fast. Thank you so much :-)